# What's wrong with my Angular JS HTTP Request Calls?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, post, request

I have two nested HTTP Requests. The first GET goes to `leadsData.php` to get the JSON file. The second one POSTs the JSON Data into `leads.php` to render the page. The goal is to show the response of `leads.php`. I do not believe my second Request (the POST) is sending the data properly for some reason because when the `$scope.content` is printed, it doesn't come back with data.

Wanted to share with you all to see if there's some basic thing I maybe forgetting.

The goal is to successfully send `$scope.haha` and print out `$scope.content`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $filter, $window) {


  //Load Prospective Students
  $scope.LoadProspectiveStudents = function() {
    //first HTTP Call
    $http.get("leadsData.php").
    then(function(response) {
        //gets the data ready and stores into haha
        $scope.haha = response.data;
        //second HTTP Call and stores into content
        $http.post("leads.php", $scope.haha)
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.content = response.data;
          })
      },
      function(response) {
        $scope.myData = "Uh oh! Something went wrong";
      });

    $scope.sortBy = function(x) {
      $scope.myData = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myData, x);
    }
  }



});
```

Comment: first check that your api is returning something in response or not for leads.php and what it is returning??

Comment: it is .... I'm able to print out the content from `leads.php`. It's just that the content doesn't have any of the data I'm passing in from `leadsData.php`

Comment: that means you are saying you are getting value of $scope.content?? And if this is true what else you want??

Comment: good question man ... $scope.content right now is barebones. It's not being passed with any data that I'm sending through with the first HTTP. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: no..i am still confused....when you are using word "content" from first call..what does that mean?? Because you have declared a variable named "content" in scope for second api response.

Comment: Please share logs for `$scope.haha` and `$scope.content`.
>>> small snippets will do

Comment: expand it to accept error callback: `$http.post("leads.php", $scope.haha).then((res) => {...}, (err) => {...})`

Comment: Are you sure that the second data request should be a POST request? In general data requests are done with a GET request. Show us the PHP code that processes the request. Or test it with Postman or Curl.